# How to make sure that all data are pushed to the array before resolving promise?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, promise

Here is my code:

```
let promise = new Promise(( resolve, reject ) => {
            let dataArray: Array<Object> = [];
            d3.csvParse(csvData, ( data, error ) => {
                if ( error ) reject('error occurred while parsing csv');
                dataArray.push(data);
            });
            resolve(dataArray);
        });
```

I am using d3 to parse the csv file that is fetched from the server. 
What I am basically trying to do is make sure the parsing is done before returning the promise/object, so I pass it to another function (not shown here). Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have read the documentation of csvParse and you can simple change your code with this

```
dataArray=d3.csvParse(csvData);
resolve(dataArray);
```

You don't need to add every row to array into the function because the csvParse will return an array when it finishes to parse

Comment: https://runkit.com/587b513664a8d4001433714a/587b513664a8d4001433714b

You need to omit the callback function or you'll only have the columns headers in `dataArray`

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The problem here is that the promise is always being rejected, any ideas why? I'll try omitting the callback as @Booster2ooo suggested.

Comment: It gets rejected because the 2nd argument of csvParse is the index of the line, not an error. So, as soon as it reaches index 1, the condition is met and the promise gets rejected. https://github.com/d3/d3-dsv/blob/master/README.md#csvParse

Comment: You have to pass the right string to csvParse function if you don't want to have bad response data.